# How to force network analyst to use metero station?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, network-analyst, multimodal-network

I'm new to use multimodal network analyst .I use [esri tutorial](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00470000005v000000) for multimodal network analyst.It was very interesting for me .What i need is that i want to force network analyst to use metero station for network analyst .for example in esri tutorial multimodal network i don't want to route from street to street like the below image and i'd like to use metero station.How can i force network analyst to use metero station ?

thanks for advance[image]

Comment: Why don't you include a stop at the Metro station in between the start and end of the route you want to solve?

Comment: I suppose that user want to use metero and go to a street and user just use two stops .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you said, let's consider that you want to minimize the walking distance from point A to point B. Stated like this, you need to solve your model based on the minimum walking distance, which means that the "cost" of the metro is "zero". This will force network analyst to use metro more often, though you will avoid using metro in trivial cases like if points A and B are 20 m apart and the closest metro station is 40 meters away.

Comment: Thats right. is that possible to show metero station names in direction window? thnx